# Border around one link in Wordpress Navigation bar

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to put a 1px border around one link in my Wordpress navigation. I found a similar post on this but it wasn't in Wordpress so it didn't help too much but this is what I want to do for my Go Virtual link:
[image]

The link to the site is: http://testsite.we-are-prodigy.com/

When I use the code:

```
.menu-item-1864 {
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I get this:
[image]

I want the border around just the words and not the whole box.

Comment: I would go with the `nth-child` CSS property. Looks like you got individual classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the link is the same height as the menu. After taking a quick look at the site, I noticed there is span tags inside the links. So you could change your selector to style the span inside. You could then add some padding for breathing room. Something like this.

```
.menu-item-1864 span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each link in your menu is in a `li` tag that has, among other classes, a unique class for that link. For example, it may look like this:

```
<ul id="primary-menu" class="nav-menu">
  <li class="menu-item menu-item-24"><a ...>Word</a></li>
</ul>
```

Find the list item you want to target and then add your CSS just for that. In the above, it would be something like:

```
.menu-item-24 {border: 1px solid #000;}
```

**Update**

Your theme won't allow this as-is. You'll need to change the spacing/padding on the list item and link as well. The way your current theme is set up, your links have a ton of padding on the top to center them vertically. You would need to trim some padding on the top, add some on the bottom, and then adjust the sizing of the list item to make it fit again.

Instead of a border, you could use a background color on the list item. That would achieve a similar "call out" effect if you don't know how to adjust the paddings and margins, etc.

Comment: When I do the css you listed, it puts a box around the entire thing. I will add that to my description above. I want it around the word only like the photo. I have found many ways to put a border around the whole thing but not the word.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use nth-child because if you try using WordPress specific class/id it's can change if you edit the menu using Joe's answer.

```
.nav-menu li:nth-child(4) {border: 1px solid;}
```

:nth-child(4) is the best solution
http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/